# Custom USB CDC Device Missing After C# GUI Crashes

Tags: c#, usb, registry

I'm using win7-64bit

I am in the process of developing a user interface for a USB CDC device (used as a flash programmer) I am adding in exception handlers and constantly testing, but whenever something does go wrong and the program crashes, the USB device disappears from device manager and will not reconnect. I uninstall and reinstall the driver (which I have made automatic in the c# GUI) but this doesn't fix it either. Nor does resetting the computer, changing USB ports, etc.. The only way I know to fix it is to delete the registry entries for the specific PID / VID stuff and then unplug the USB and plug it back in. Windows the reinstalls it (because it still has the inf file) and it works perfectly. This shouldn't be an issue in the release version, but for testing it has been a real problem constantly going through that process.

My question is why is this happening?

Comment: Just realized the situation is much simpler to explain that I thought. It apparently has nothing to do with my C# program... it's just the act of unplugging the USB cable and then it NEVER works again until I erase certain values in the registry. Then I can plug in and it works once and if unplugged stops working. The exact apparent behavior is that it plays the USB connect sound effect halfway through followed by an immediate disconnect. It briefly shows up in device manager console but it seems like windows recognizes it and disconnects. Changed PID / VID which worked for 2 unplug/plugs =)

Comment: Maybe your device's firmware is doing something funny.  Do you have a USB protocol analyzer to check that hypothesis?  Could you figure out exactly which registry keys are causing the problem and post them?  Does the device show up in "Other devices" or anywhere else in the Device Manager when it is not working?